# Load UIViewController from UIView(.xib) Button Action

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have created a UIView in Interface Builder.I have a button in it.Can i load any ViewController in the app by tapping the Button of UIView ? My UIView is not under Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
YourViewController *aView = [[YourViewController alloc]
                              initWithNibName:@"xibName" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:aView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I am trying to load UIViewController from UIView.UIView does not have presentViewController method.

Comment: Than you can do like this [yourViewObject addSubview:aView.view];

Comment: In this case just the UIViewController.view is visible.I need the ViewController as rootviewController

Comment: You cannot add it as rootviewController but you can add it as [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:aView.view]; or
    [view.superview addSubview:aView.view];

Answer (score 0):

you could use a NSNotification to inform a ViewController for presenting another ViewController.

More information here:

[NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Show the ViewController with:

```
ViewController *viewController = ...;

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Another option is, calling delegate from your button.

Comment: I am trying to load UIViewController from UIView.UIView does not have presentViewController method.

Comment: Yeah, you should inform a ViewController with NSNotification / Delegate to present your Controller.